# python requests multi-layer proxy

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

Is it possible to create multi-layered proxy?

ie.

```
my IP address -> proxyA -> proxyB -> targetURL
```

I am aware of making a requests using single-layer proxy using python or using `Tor` (both using Python's `requests` library) but I am exploring ways to create multi-layered proxy.

Kindly help if anybody knows any idea or hint or sample code how to do this.

Comment: what is a proxy? SOCKS proxy? The one like Squid that accepts CONNECT request? Or a SSH tunnel that is transparent to socket users? Generally speaking, it is not a python problem until you can be more specific on your system design.

Comment: what I meant by proxy here is proxy address similar like what you can get in sslproxies.org. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.